# Improve performance of using NOW() function in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a MySQL query from PHP (for preventing brute force):

```
 $stmt = $sql_connection->prepare(
        'SELECT 1 FROM `ip_login` WHERE `ip` = ? AND `when` > ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 SECOND)');
```

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the database server from calculating `ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 SECOND)` for each record with something like:

```
$stmt = $sql_connection->prepare(
        'SELECT 1 FROM `ip_login` JOIN
            (SELECT ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 SECOND) as 'when') as 'time'
        ON `ip_login`.`when` > `time`.`when`
        WHERE `ip_login`.`ip` = ?');
```

The reason I don't calculate the time in PHP code is that if there are multiple HTTP servers working with the same database, I don't need to keep their time in sync.

1. Is it worth it to make the query that complicated?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: it isn't calculated for each record

Comment: Thanks @ysth Is the behavior documented somewhere to put as a reference here?

Comment: When in doubt about an execution plan in mysql use `explain` to see what it is doing. That should show you were you slow down is. This likely is an XY problem and not a PHP issue.

Answer (score 0):

We can't know for sure unless we know more about your database's structure.

Most likely you don't have indexes on 'ip_login.when', also why are you making a self join when you can have 2 WHERE clauses?

You can limit the results afterwards with LIMIT.

And always as user3783243 mentioned, you can use EXPLAIN to see why your query is going slow.